# How to bind integer Input value to Slider

Tags: sapui5

I want to have a Slider and an Input control, both for one specific value.

The user should be able to use either the input field or the slider to input his value.

If the user changes the value on the Slider, the input field should show the Slider's value. And if the user inputs something in the input field, the Slider should move to the corresponding value.
Currently, I am creating a `JSONModel` with the value as a property to bind:

```js
let model = new JSONModel({
  valueName: 10
});
settings.setModel(model);
```

Now, when I am changing the value on the slider, the update of the input field is working fine. But if I'm entering a value in the input field, the Slider does **not** move to the value.

Why is that so and how do I solve my problem?

```xml
<Slider value="{/valueName}" step="10" width="200px" />
<Input value="{/valueName}" type="Number" width="50px" />
```

---

Since the given solutions only worked for integer values a follow up question for float values was created [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583975/sapui5-synchrone-input-and-slider-for-float-inputs)

Comment: Simply add an appropriate data `type` to one of the property bindings as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935545/5846045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was baffled by this at first. The reason appears to be that the value is saving as a string (in spite of you explicitly specifying number or clearly binding the value in the initial model to a numeric value).
I checked this by handling the liveChange event off the Input, retrieving the model value of valueName, doing a parseInt on the value and then setting the Slider to that value.
This causes the slider to update as I change the Input.

Controller:

```
handleChange: function(){
    var slider = this.getView().byId("slider");
    var val = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/valueName");
    slider.setValue(parseInt(val));
}
```

XML View:

```
<Slider id="slider" value="{/valueName}" min="0" max="100" step="10" width="200px" />
<Input textAlign="Center" value="{/valueName}" type="Number" width="50px" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="handleChange"/>
```

The caveat was if I wanted to update the slider to, say, 70 I would need to key in the 0 first (as the slider settings as they stand convert the value to min (0) or 10 the moment I type a number - given the correct behaviour of liveUpdate). There are ways to work around this but I thought I'd get you the answer and you can figure out what to do from there.

Ultimately i think this is a bug. **EDIT** - *this is not a bug - please refer comment by Boghyon below this Answer*

Comment: Unfortunately/Fortunately, this is **not** a bug. Input stores the value in string --> Slider awaits `float` but gets a string from the model --> doesn't update its value. This is by design. Applications should explicitly specify a type as explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935545/5846045.
We might ask why it then works the other way around (Slider --> Input): ManagedObject implicitly casts values for string type already: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/eb97aa6237bad9d82bcf2ae586e53429b6927ec2/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L1444, but *only* for the string type.

Answer (score 2):

> The user should be able to use either the input field or the slider to input his value.

In case you were not aware, you could use the built in Tooltip input feature:

```xml
<Slider
  showAdvancedTooltip="true"
  showHandleTooltip="false"
  inputsAsTooltips="true"
/>
```

Gives you this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Slider awaits a value of **type *float***.

> [image: SAPUI5 Slider value type]

The input field, however, evaluates inputs as *string*.

You can solve it declaratively by assigning an appropriate `type` to the binding info object:

- **Either** assign `sap/ui/model/type/String`* to Slider's `value` binding type ⇒ Formats the string value from the model to a *float* type prior to passing the value to the Slider.
  Float value manipulated from the Slider will be converted back to a *string* value before storing it in the model as a result of two-way binding with the String type.
- **Or** assign `sap/ui/model/type/Float`* to Input's `value` binding type ⇒ Stores the value as *number* in the model. The Slider can then use the number value directly.

Here is a **demo of the above approaches: https://jsbin.com/sodihub/edit?js,output**

Using the `type` feature in binding will allow *parsing*, *formatting*, and even *validating* the model value before updating the control while still keeping the two-way data binding mode.

---

* In case of binding with ODataModel, require `sap/ui/model/odata/type/Decimal|String` instead!

Comment: Your demo does work fine. I have now stumbled across another problem. If you set the `step` of the slider to `0.1` only the integer values are shown in the Input field. How can you solve this? If I should open a new question for that please let me know.

Comment: Follow up question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583975/sapui5-synchrone-input-and-slider-for-float-inputs

Comment: @IceRevenge The demo is fixed now and I added more information to it. Thanks for letting me know about the issue!