# sap.m.Input's value binding with type="Number" clears the input field

Tags: sapui5

This is a follow-up question to [How to bind integer Input value to Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930668/how-to-bind-integer-input-value-to-slider).

I have found out that the demo solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57935545/5846045) only works when there are integer values in the slider and the language of your browser is set to English.

Snippet from the demo:

> ```xml
> <Input xmlns="sap.m"
>   xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
>   core:require="{FloatType: 'sap/ui/model/type/Float'}"
>   type="Number"
>   value="{
>     path: '/value',
>     type: 'FloatType'
>   }"
> />
> ```

To reproduce the issue:

1. Go to the settings of your browser.
2. Set e.g. German as the language.
3. Reload the demo.

If the `step` of the slider is then set to an integer value (e.g. `1`), values are all shown correctly in the input field.
With `step="0.1"`, however, only integer values are shown whereas float values (e.g. "1,4") are hidden, causing warning in the browser console:

> The specified value "1,4" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.

Any ideas or better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, remove `type="Number"` from the `<Input>` control.

The property `type="Number"` in UI5 shouldn't be used together with `value`-binding anyway, due to browsers implementing HTML `<input type="number">` behavior slightly differently, according to the API reference:

> **Only the default value `sap.m.InputType.Text` may be used** in combination with data model formats. [(Source)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/03435d913b3b904d151da3012d9d2eb0b1e21b65/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Input.js#L172).

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:

A formatter is needed that replaces the "," with a ".":

```
formatStringToNumber: sNumber => parseFloat(sNumber.replace(","))
```

In the binding of the input then simply add the formatter:

```
<Input 
  width= "50px" 
  type="Number"
  value="{
    path: '/passageWidth',
    formatter: 'formatStringToNumber',
    type: 'FloatType',
    formatOptions: { emptyString: 0 }
}"/>
```

Comment: be aware that using a formatter make the binding one-way